# Assigning messages from STDOUT and STDERR to TCL variables

Tags: perl, tcl, stdout, stderr

Im looking to get some organization to the output of a command executed in a TCL script in Windows. The situation is that I have a tcl script that eventually calls a perl script. Something like this:

The perl script outputs results to both stdout and stderr:

```
#print message to STDOUT by default
print "process A running ...";
...
if ($fail) {
    #print to STDERR
    print STDERR "Process A failed.";
}
```

Initially, all I wanted to see from the tcl script was the messages from the prints to STDERR, but now I want to see both. Is there a way to get the messages from print going to stdout to be saved to one tcl variable and the messages from the print going to stderr to be saved in another tcl variable? This was my attempt in tcl to get this to work:

```
puts "Running perl script ..."
catch {[set stdout_var [exec perl C:/myScript.pl >@stdout]]} err_msg
puts "\n\nerrmsg:\n$err_msg"
puts "\n\nstdout:\n$stdout_var"
```

Doing this, I get only the messages printed to STDERR in the err_msg variable (so I'm half way there), however, the stdout_var variable never gets set to anything. I was hoping it would be set to the messages to STDOUT, but that was not the case. If I remove the >@stdout, stdout_var still does not get assigned and err_msg contains all messages printed to STDERR and STDOUT.

Thanks for the input!

Comment: Redirect one of them to a temporary file.

Answer (score 1):

There's an example [here on the Tcl wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1036)

```
 puts "Running perl script ..."

 set pipe [open "| perl C:/myScript.pl"]
 set standard_output [read -nonewline $pipe]
 set exit_status 0
 if {[catch {close $pipe} standard_error] != 0} {
     global errorCode
     if {"CHILDSTATUS" == [lindex $errorCode 0]} {
         set exit_status [lindex $errorCode 2]
     }
 }
 puts "exit status: $exit_status"
 puts "\n\nstdout:\n$standard_output"
 puts "\n\nstderr:\n$standard_error"
```

Comment: A little more complicated that I hoped for, but I gave it a try. $standard_error contains only the error messages, which is good. However, $stnadard_output contains BOTH the stnadard output and standard error messages. I guess i could process that var some more to remove them but I was hoping they wouldnt have been there in the first place.

Comment: I'd've expected that to work. Unless the perl script's been told to spit the errors to both channels; I've been known to put such things in for debugging and then wonder for ages afterwards what was causing them (when it was in fact my own code!) Perhaps you've done the same?